# How do I list edges without repetition?

Tags: python-3.x, graph-theory

I have created a function to list all edges of a graph. I need help on how to modify my code to get the correct output *without edge repetition*. Here is what I tried:

```
def edges(A):
    node_list = [ ]
    for vertex in A:
        for neighb in A[ vertex ]:
              node_list.append(( vertex, neighb ))

    return(node_list)

data = {
    'A' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'B' : ['C','A'],
    'C' : ['C', 'D'],
    'D' : ['E'],
    'E' : []
}

print("List of edges: ", edges(data))
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), 
('B', 'A'), ('C', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E')]
```

Comment: By repetition, do you mean that e.g. (A, B) and (B, A) should count as one?

Comment: In that case, you can use a simple `if` statement to check whether `(neighb, vertex)` is already in the list of edges, and only add it if it isn't.

Comment: Your graph seems to be a directed graph where all edges are unique. Please clarify what do you mean by without edge repetition.  
If you want one edge out of (A,B) and (B,A) etc. then you can add *if ((neighb,vertex) or (vertex,neighb)) not in node_list:* just over node_list.append

Comment: YES I wanted one edge out of (A,B) and (B,A).  Lalit, your suggestion gives the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is using a set to store the edges, and keep each edge internally sorted (i.e., node with lower lexicographical value will be first). With a set you won't have duplicate edges, and ordering each edge internally will help avoiding keeping both (A, B) and (B, A). In case of directed graphs you can skip the node sorting part. Python implementation:

```
def edges(A):
    edges = set()
    for vertex in A:
        for neighb in A[vertex]:
            first = min(vertex, neighb)
            second = neighb if first == vertex else vertex
            edges.add((first, second))

    return list(edges)

data = {
    'A' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'B' : ['C','A'],
    'C' : ['C', 'D'],
    'D' : ['E'],
    'E' : []
}

print("List of edges: ", edges(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

idk about python but you can keep a boolean isTraversed for edges with default value false.If the egde is traversed change value to true. And in a if statement you can print the edge if it's isTraversed value is false.